# Google Recaptcha not hiding on mobile

Tags: css, mobile-safari, recaptcha-v3

I have a website
https://toitopublishing.com

It has google recaptcha which hides perfectly using `visibility:hidden` on desktop browsers. It refuses to hide on IOS Safari/ Chrome.

I have tried

```
opacity: 0;
z-index:-9999;
```

And also tried assigning opacity using javascript after document loads. It isn’t working.

Do note i have added link to privacy policy on the form so it is legal to hide the logo as per google.

Edit : display:none cannot be used on Google Recaptcha. It disables spam checking altogether.

Comment: better use display:none with css and media queries

Comment: @Sfili_81 display:none on google recaptcha disables spam checking

Comment: right ;) I have not thought about spam checking